# express-angular-node: Voting Application

Tags: angularjs, express

the following are my two files for a simple voting app and for some reason the button are not increasing the count only when you refresh the voting.html page does both count increase by one. Your help is appreciated.

```
    <!-- voting.html-->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Voting</title>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myFirstApp', []);

            app.controller('CounterCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
                console.log('CounterCtrl started');

                // $scope.countA = 0;
                // $scope.countB = 0;

                // $scope.Acrease = function() {
                //  console.log('Acrease() called');
                //  $scope.countA++;
                // };
                // $scope.Bcrease = function() {
                //  console.log('Bcrease() called');
                //  //if($scope.count>0) $scope.count--;$scope.count++;
                //  $scope.countB++;
                // };

                function getItemsA() {
                    $http.get('/voteA').then(function(res) {
                        $scope.countA = res.data;
                        //$scope.countA = res.json(A);

                        console.log('/voteA: ', $scope.countA);
                    });
                }

                getItemsA();

                function getItemsB() {
                    $http.get('/voteB').then(function(res) {
                        $scope.countB = res.data;

                        //$scope.countA = res.json(A);
                        console.log('/voteB: ', $scope.countB);
                    });
                }

                getItemsB();

                // $scope.addItem = function() {
                //  console.log('addItem()\t newItem=', $scope.newItem);
                //  $http.get('/list/add/' + $scope.newItem).then(getItems);
                // };
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myFirstApp">

        <div ng-controller="CounterCtrl">
            <p>Count of A Vote: <b>{{countA}}</b></p>
            <p>Count of B Vote: <b>{{countB}}</b></p>

            <input type="button" ng-click="getItemsA()" value="A">
            <input type="button" ng-click="getItemsB()" value="B">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>


/***server.js***/
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.listen(3001, function() {
    console.log('Listening on 3001');
});

// Mount the public directory at /
app.use('/', express.static('./public'));


/********************************************
 * This code is for voting.html
 *******************************************/

// initialize the votes variables
var A = 0 ;
var B = 0 ;

// add the voteA
app.get('/voteA', function(req,res) {
    //res.json(A);
    A++
    res.json(A);

});

// add the voteB
app.get('/voteB', function(req,res) {
    //res.json(A);
    B++
    res.json(B);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is angular1 I presume.

I think your problem is that your ng-click is calling a function which is not in scope. I believe you should create scope functions:

```
$scope.getItemsA = function() {
    $http.get('/voteA').then(function(res) {
       $scope.countA = res.data;
        console.log('response recieved');
     });
  };
```

Hope it helps..